# XQuery, get element with same value?

Tags: xquery

xml

`<books>    <book>       <author>Gambardella, Tim</author>    </book>    <book>       <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>    </book>    <book>       <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>    </book> </books>`

How get authors with same name?

I tried searching but didn't find even working examples for finding the same strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is a grouping problem e.g.

```
for $author in books/book/author 
  group by $prename := $author => substring-after(',') => normalize-space() 
return 
  <group prename="{$prename}">{$author}</group>
```